# Angular 5 / CLI 1.5.0: .map files are not generated

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I installed Angular 5 / CLI 1.5.0:

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 8.7.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.32
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.35
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.2
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

I created a test project wint `ng new` and immediately run `ng serve`:

```
ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2017-11-08T22:24:20.928Z
Hash: 52facc1fd1cf476d4b1b
Time: 8407ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 20.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 550 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 33.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 7.02 MB [initial] [rendered]
```

For some reason it doesn't generate .map files to allow debugging in browser. With Angular 4 it was fine.

How to fix that?

Comment: Not able to repro this, but I am using typescript 2.6.1. I can't imaging that would be the solution, though. My `@schematics/angular` version in 0.1.0, too. I get maps. Good luck!

Comment: @R.Richards: Thank you! Do you have `chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map` instead of just  `chunk {main} main.bundle.js`, right?

Comment: I use F12 in Chrome to open the dev tools. Go to Sources. Ctrl-P, then I can see any of my *.ts* files, and the tool status bar shows that the source is mapped from which ever file I choose.

Comment: @R.Richards: Sorry, I mean does `ng serve` prints `chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map` as it was in Angular 4 or just `chunk {main} main.bundle.js` (as it became after I upgraded to Angular 5)?

Comment: No. The map file listing in the `ng serve` output is no longer there. I guess I never noticed that until I just ran them side-by-side. I have not seen any adverse effects as a result.

Comment: @R.Richards: Ok, thank you for checking this! Something is definitely broken: though I've managed to make mappings working for some time, after a bunch of changes in my project's TS files it stopped working again. Not sure even how to check what's wrong in Webpack.